# Ajax login to a website and follow redirect

Tags: ajax, post, authentication, web

I want to login to a website and follow redirection whit ajax or XMLHttpRequest or any thing else exept php.

Actually whene i try to do it, i have error "302 Moved Temporarily" but the webpage is the right page so i don't know why i get this error.

The website is an external website (not on my server).

This is my code :

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       url: "http://website/index.php",        
       data: { username: "myuser", password: "123456" },
       success: function(data) {
            console.log("success ", data.response);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("error ", data.error);
        },
        dataType: "html"               
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

If you try use ajax outside your domain, you will probably get this error message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/path/filename. Origin
>   null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The reason you get this error message is because of the Same-origin policy. The policy permits scripts running on pages originating from the same site to access each other's data with no specific restrictions, but prevents scripts access to data that is stored on a different domain.

This could be a problem if you are trying to access publicly hosted data, but there are ways around it.

Here is the list of methods:

- Implement CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)
- Use JSONP (JSON Padding)
- Use postMessage method
- Setting up a local proxy

**CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)**

CORS is a mechanism that allows resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain the resource originated from. In particular, JavaScript's AJAX calls can use the XMLHttpRequest mechanism. Such "cross-domain" requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which the browser and the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the cross-origin request. It is more useful than only allowing same-origin requests, but it is more secure than simply allowing all such cross-origin requests.

**JSONP (JSON Padding)**

JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a communication technique used in JavaScript programs running in web browsers to request data from a server in a different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because of the same-origin policy. JSONP takes advantage of the fact that browsers do not enforce the same-origin policy on `<script>` tags.

Because of the same origin policy, we can not make cross domain AJAX requests, but we can have `<script>` tags that load javascript files from other domains. JSONP uses this exception in order to make cross domain requests by dynamically creating a `<script>` tag with necessary URL.

**postMessage method**

window.postMessage method is part of HTML5 introductions. It allows communication between window frames without being subject to same origin policy. Using postMessage() one can trigger a message event with attached data on another window, even if the window has different domain, port or a protocol. The frame where the event is triggered must add an event listener in order to be able to respond.

Let's see an example. Assume, we are on http://example.com (1) website and would like to make a request to http://example2.net (2) domain. We first must obtain a reference to (2) window. This can be either iframe.contentWindow, window.open, or window.frames[]. For our case it's best to create a hidden iframe element and send messages to it.

**Setup local proxy**

This method overcomes same origin policy by proxying content on another domain through itself. Thus making cross-domain issue irrelevant. To use this method you will either a) setup your server as a reverse proxy to fetch content from another server or b) write a script that would do that.

This cross domain querying solution works because you actually loading content from your own domain. You request the URL and the proxy script on your server loads the content and passes it over to you.

http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html You can visit this link if you want to learn about these methods in details. There is also a jquery plugin named ajax cross origin to tackle similar issues.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18567953)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated my answer to contain more information.

Comment: Sorry but i forgot to tell you the website is already with Cross Origin enable. So there no problem about Cross Origin.